# subcaption package not working

Tags: floats, subcaption

I am using miktex with all packages up to date, and I am trying an example from `subcaption` document as below

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subcaptionblock}{.2\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics{cat}
        \caption{A cat}\label{cat}
    \end{subcaptionblock}%
    \begin{subcaptionblock}{.2\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics{elephant}
        \caption{An elephant}\label{elephant}
    \end{subcaptionblock}%
    \caption{Two animals}\label{animals}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

What I got is

[image]

What is wrong?

Comment: Why are the blocks only 20% text width? From the image I see subcaption doing the right thing, but the block width and the size of the images are not coordinated. What did you expect would happen?

Comment: @daleif Thank you so much for comment. I misunderstand the subcaptionbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subcaptionblock}{.2\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{A cat}\label{cat}
    \end{subcaptionblock}%
    \begin{subcaptionblock}{.2\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{An elephant}\label{elephant}
    \end{subcaptionblock}%
    \caption{Two animals}\label{animals}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for help : )